# MQGet and MQInput from the same queue

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

I've come across a curious detail in the legacy integration solution based on WebSphere MQ 7.0.1.3 and WebSphere Message Broker 7.0.0.7. There are 2 message flows:

The 1st flow is a case of MQ Request-Reply pattern. After MQPut it has a MQGet node that gets the message by correlation ID from queue "MQ_BIS_IN".

The 2nd flow is a kind of a one-way router that starts with a MQInput node (without any filters) that listens on the queue "MQ_GW_IN".

Interestingly, "MQ_BIS_IN" is an alias for "MQ_GW_IN" queue. My first thought was that the 2 flows would interfere in a bad way, basically the "omnivorous" MQInput would ruin the Request-Reply thing. But they seem to somehow get along.

I am going to reproduce this configuration in a test environment to determine if their behaviour is stable under load. Nevertheless, does anybody know if there are some rules of precedence between concurrent read operation from the same queue? Does it matter that there's an alias to the queue?

Comment: Are these 2 separate flows, or just 2 paths in one flow?

Comment: These are 2 separate message flows deployed to the same execution group.

Comment: Is the MQInput only browsing the input queue?

Comment: Both the MQInput and the MQGet node can be configured to look for particular msgId's or correlation Id's only, or to pick up the items on the queue in a determined order, or only pick up complete groups of messages - so there doesn't need to be a conflict here.

Answer (score 0):

Both the MQInput and the MQGet node can be configured to look for particular msgId's or correlation Id's only, or to pick up the items on the queue in a determined order, or only pick up complete groups of messages - so there doesn't need to be a conflict here.